# How to run bundle from PHP script

Tags: php, ruby, bundler

I'm writing a webhook to automatically publish a site when I push to GitHub. Part of the process requires that I build the site with

```
bundle exec middleman build --clean
```

I'm trying to invoke that with a PHP script, the script called by the GitHub webhook, so the user is `www-data`. No matter what I try, however, I'm getting an error that `bundle` cannot be found.

How can I run a  `bundle` command from a PHP script?

Comment: Make sure that it's in the path for the user www-data?

Comment: The Ruby gem environment needs a lot of variables set or it won't work, and the most important is `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. First, I [installed rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#installation) as a multi-user installation to ensure the `www-data` account can access it.

```
$ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```

Install the desired ruby version, in my case 2.3.1, then set rvm to use it:

```
$ rvm install 2.3.1
$ rvm use 2.3.1
```

Run `gem` to install any gems that are needed. Because rvm is a multi-user installation, these gems are stored to the system and not your specific user.

```
$ gem install packagename
```

I don't know if this is necessary, but I would close the SSH session and reopen it. rvm messes with environment variables, so better safe than sorry.

Run `env` to print all environment variables. `printenv` also works if `env` doesn't for some reason. You'll get a big list of everything set, you only need the ruby-related ones. **Do not copy/paste these values, they are examples I pulled from my system. Yours will be different!**

```
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/steven/bin:/home/steven/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
rvm_bin_path=/usr/local/rvm/bin
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
IRBRC=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/.irbrc
MY_RUBY_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1
rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm
rvm_prefix=/usr/local
rvm_ruby_string=ruby-2.3.1
GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.3.1
```

Now we need PHP to recognize these variables. You'll need to find the right file on your system, which can be tricky. I don't have a way of knowing which one is correct, I used trial and error.

The file on my system is `/etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`. Add **all** of the environment variables you previously grabbed into this file with the below format. Note that you DO need `PATH` in here as well!

```
env[rvm_path] = /usr/local/rvm
env[rvm_prefix] = /usr/local
```

Now restart `php-fpm`. Your service name may be different from mine; I'm using the 5.6 build from [ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php).

Ubuntu 15.04 and newer (systemd):

```
$ sudo systemctl restart php5.6-fpm
```

Ubuntu 14.10 and newer:

```
$ sudo service php5.6-fpm restart
```

Finally, in the script itself you'll need to `cd` to the directory you're running the `bundle` command from. My short script is this:

```bash
cd /opt/slate
/usr/bin/git reset --hard
/usr/bin/git pull
bundle exec middleman build --clean
cp -R /opt/slate/build/* /var/www/docs
```

Works for me!